# Generating Wrong Barcode (Code_39) in Zxing

Tags: android, android-studio, zxing

**Introduction**

I am generating a Barcode in zxing inside my android app. But it is not able to scan in any of the scanner apps. I have tried to create code 39 for the same number online but I am getting a different one online and that's working fine.

**My Code**

```
public static Bitmap generateCode39BarCode(String Value) {
    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    String finaldata = Uri.encode(Value, "utf-8");

    BitMatrix bm = null;
    try {
        bm = writer.encode(finaldata, BarcodeFormat.CODE_39, 150, 150);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap ImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(180, 40, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

    for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++) {//width
        for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++) {//height
            ImageBitmap.setPixel(i, j, bm.get(i, j) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    return ImageBitmap;
}
```

*I am passing 908765678 as input to this function.*

**Output**

The output bitmap I am getting is-
[image]
But if you scan this with any scanner app it is unable to be scanned.

***Can anyone suggest a solution to this?***

Comment: I think you didn't encode 908765678. I run your barcode through the debugger and jump over the first character which is a * (a star). The * is something like a stop character. The decoder stops if it find it in the code. Make sure that the following line didn't add a star at the beginning (and perhaps at the end): ```String finaldata = Uri.encode(Value, "utf-8");```

Comment: can you please elaborate. where is it actually creating * ??

Comment: You have to debug your own code and you have to look into the content of the variable "finaldata". I'm not sure but I think your call to Uri.encode do some weird things.

Comment: so any suggestion instead of the encoding it?

Comment: First you should look into the content of finaldata before writer.encode is called. What value is hold by the variable?